# Create dropdown list from query - JSON

Tags: javascript, json, drop-down-menu

I have carried out a querytask in javascript that queries 2 layers within a single service. It returns a couple of values including a local authority. I've created a JSON file with that local authority name and what I'd like to do is create a drop down showing the local authority url values (resulting from the queryTask) that are contained in the JSON string. This is the queryTask code:

```
     var queryTask = new QueryTask("http://rest/services/live/SEARCH/MapServer/2");
     var query = new Query();
     query.returnGeometry = true;
     query.outFields = [
       "POSTCODE"
     ];

     on(dom.byId("execute"), "click", execute);

     function execute() {
         //
         query.text = dom.byId("Postcode").value;
         queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
     };

     function showResults(results) {
         var resultItems = [];
         var inBuffer = [];
         var resultCount = results.features.length;
         for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
             inBuffer.push(results.features[i].geometry);
             var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
             var graphic = results.features[i];
             graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
             map.graphics.add(graphic);

             var strNum = 100;
             var newExtent = graphic.geometry.getExtent();
             newExtent.xmin = newExtent.xmin - strNum;
             newExtent.ymin = newExtent.ymin - strNum;
             newExtent.xmax = newExtent.xmax + strNum;
             newExtent.ymax = newExtent.ymax + strNum;
             map.setExtent(newExtent);

             for (var attr in featureAttributes){
                 resultItems.push("<b>" + attr + ":</b>  " + featureAttributes[attr] + "<br>");
             }
             resultItems.push("<br>");
         }
         var query2 = new Query();
         query2.geometry = geometryEngine.union(inBuffer);
         query2.returnGeometry = false;
         query2.outFields = ["NAME", "OBJECTID"];
         var queryTask2 = new QueryTask("http://rest/services/live/SEARCH/MapServer/15");
         //resultItems.push("Before process");
         queryTask2.execute(query2, function (results2) {
             //resultItems.push("Before");
             for (var j = 0; j < results2.features.length; j++) {
                 resultItems.push("<b>Local Authority:</b>  " + results2.features[j].attributes.NAME + "<br/>" + "<b>Object id:</b>" + results2.features[j].attributes.OBJECTID + "<br/>");
             }
             //resultItems.push("After");
             var lstr = "";
             for (var j = 2; j <= resultItems.length; j++) {
             lstr = lstr + resultItems[j] + "" + j.toString();

             }
             dom.byId("info").innerHTML = lstr;

         });
```

And this is an example of how the JSON is constructed:

```
{   "Local authority": {
    "objectid": "1",
    "name": "Kent",
    "service": [
        "Libraries": "url",
        "Bins": "url",
        "Dog walking": "url"
     ]
},
    "objectid": "2",
    "name": "Devon",
    "service": [
        "Libraries": "url",
        "Bins": "url",
        "Dog walking": "url"
       ]

        }
```

I hope someone could help  - spent the whole day on it and I can't work it out. Thank you.

Comment: Your JSON is all over the place. Please correct it. If your request is to convert JSON to an HTML drop-down menu then there is no need for all your query code.

Comment: But I need the code to return the initial local authority that I hope to then check for in the JSON..

Comment: Yea that's fine, but how is your query related to that. In the example you've described the query has already been made. It doesn't matter how it is made, only the result from it. That result is your JSON. That's what you want to know how to form into a drop-down menu. Is that correct?

Comment: My result is for example Kent. The service I'm querying gives me that result when I input a postcode. The JSON file is external and separate from the service and contains related urls to each local authority. Assuming I get Kent from my query, I want to then 'parse the JSON so that I can create a dropdown list of the Kent url services on it. Sorry if it sounds a bit unclear.